# IP over USB stick sneakernet

Tags: udp, ip, usb-drive

I'm trying to implement an application that communicates using UDP over usb sticks and I'm wondering if there already are drivers for Linux / Windows that can do this already (writing sent UDP packets to disk and reading packets from disk to send them again)

Google mainly returns results for usb over IP which is the opposite of what I am looking for, does anyone know of such a driver?

Comment: Huh? Why would this ever be useful?

Comment: A friend to friend network using usb sticks (and RFC 1149, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)